# Views of panel nodes - how can you display a field from one of the panel's nodes

Tags: views, nodes, entities, panels

I've got a view of Panel nodes. I want to display the Panel title in the list, followed by the body field from a particular node contained in one of the Panel node's regions.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm trying my best to discourage everyone from using Panels Nodes at all. If you use [Panelizer](http://drupal.org/project/panelizer) instead, you get all of the same functionality, but well integrated into Core. [Issue about upgrade path](http://drupal.org/node/1353542)

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. I've considered using Panelizer already, but I can't seem to figure out how I would then be able to reuse my content nodes in other places, without also importing all of the extra items attached to the regions.